# What is the meaning of **(p2[1][0] + 1)

Tags: c, pointers

I have just started diving into pointers in C and I can't understand why 14 is the output.

I have the given code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 3
typedef int(*MyType1)[N];
typedef int(*MyType2)[N][N];

int main(int argc, int *argv[]){

    int m1[][N] = { 21,122,-13,14,56,36,17,78,92 };
    int m2[][N] = { 11,9,43,17,32,99,127,34,69 };
    MyType1 p1[] = { m1 + 1,m2 + 2,m1+2,m2,m1,m2+1};
    MyType2 p2[] = { &m2, &m1 };

    printf("%d\n", **(p2[1][0] + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

My thought was:
`**(p2[1][0] + 1)` is equivalent to `**(&m1[0] + 1)`.

Then, `&m1[0]` is the address of the first element in m1 (21), plus one increments the address to the number next to it (122).

I noticed that every plus one accessed the n + 3 number in m1 (goes down a row in m1?)  --> The question is why.

Comment: The only purpose of such a code is to confuse the reader.

Comment: Yes indeed, I am practicing in order to make sure I fully understand the subject, therefore the confusing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

`p[1]` is a pointer to `m1`.

`m1` might also have been initialized: `{{21,122,-13},{14,56,36},{17,78,92}}`.

So `p[1][0]` is a pointer to the first array: `{21, 122, -13}` but then we do some pointer arithmetic and point to the next array: `{14,56,36}` and when we dereference that we get the first element which is... `14`.